# Замена ключа в массиве

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Имеется JS массив вида

```
var cashFlowData = [{
    period: "Beginning\nBalance",
    amount: 50000
}, {
    period: "Jan",
    amount: 17000
}, {
    period: "Feb",
    amount: 14000
}, {
    period: "Mar",
    amount: -12000
}];
```

Каким образом можно изменить ключ, например, для 3 элемента, что бы было вот так:

```
var cashFlowData = [{
    period: "Beginning\nBalance",
    amount: 50000
}, {
    period: "Jan",
    amount: 17000
}, {
    period: "Feb",
    summary: 14000
}, {
    period: "Mar",
    amount: -12000
}];
```

Comment: Или может быть можно добавить на конкретную позицию элемент? какойнибудь аналог push()? Но только что бы не в конец а на конкретную позицию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код сделает ровно то, что вы просите. Дальше можете развивать эту мысль как нужно.

```
cashFlowData[2].summary = cashFlowData[2].amount
delete cashFlowData[2].amount
```

**UPD**

Касательно вставки, посмотрите на функцию [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Первый параметр - индекс начала изменения массива, второй параметр - количество удаляемых элементов, третий и последующие параметры - элементы для вставки.

В этом примере мы вставляем на позицию 0 объект с январем и 100500, при этом ничего не удаляя:

```
cashFlowData.splice(0, 0, {period: "Jan", summary: 100500})
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую) Нашел немного другой подход: cashFlowData[cashFlowData.length-0] = {period: "123",summary: "runningTotal"};

Comment: @Егор, это же просто вставка нового элемента в конец массива, если хотите вставить в середину, то так не получится.

Comment: cashFlowData.length-0, ну изменяя число можно вставить например 3 с конца) cashFlowData.length-3

Comment: @Егор, не вставить, а заменить существующий элемент